# PhP - Search massive array for value, return parent key.

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

**Q: How to Search Massive Multi-Dimensional Array for Single Value, and Return Parent Array?**

I have this massive json that represents all of the achievements in WoW.

http://us.battle.net/api/wow/data/character/achievements

I converted it into an array using json_decode. This then leaves me with a very massive array that I need to search all of its levels until I find a specific value, I then need to return the parent array of that value.

ex:

This is one small part of the decoded array.

```
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 7385
[title] => Pub Crawl
            [points] => 10
            [description] => Complete the Brewmaster scenario achievements listed below.
            [reward] => Reward: Honorary Brewmaster Keg
            [rewardItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 87528
                            [name] => Honorary Brewmaster Keg
                            [icon] => inv_holiday_brewfestbuff_01
                            [quality] => 3
                            [itemLevel] => 90
                            [tooltipParams] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [armor] => 0
                        )

                )

            [icon] => inv_misc_archaeology_vrykuldrinkinghorn
            [criteria] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20680
                            [description] => Spell No Evil
                            [orderIndex] => 0
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20681
                            [description] => Yaungolian Barbecue
                            [orderIndex] => 1
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20682
                            [description] => Binan Village All-Star
                            [orderIndex] => 2
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20683
                            [description] => The Keg Runner
                            [orderIndex] => 3
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20684
                            [description] => Monkey in the Middle
                            [orderIndex] => 4
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20685
                            [description] => Monkey See, Monkey Kill
                            [orderIndex] => 5
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20686
                            [description] => Don't Shake the Keg
                            [orderIndex] => 6
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20687
                            [description] => Party of Six
                            [orderIndex] => 7
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20688
                            [description] => The Perfect Pour
                            [orderIndex] => 8
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        ( re
                            [id] => 20689
                            [description] => Save it for Later
                            [orderIndex] => 9
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20690
                            [description] => Perfect Delivery
                            [orderIndex] => 10
                            [max] => 1
                        )

                )

            [accountWide] => 
            [factionId] => 2
        )
```

I am attempting to create a function where I can just simply enter the achievement ID, which in this exmple is `7385`, and have the parent array which would be  `[0] => Array (...);` returned, so i can then grab the achievement details from that array.

I am not sure if this is really a proper question, as I am not sure as where to start.

So far I have just started breaking the original massive array down into its 10 equally as massive categories, and then searching them each individually, but I would like to just be able to search the main array once instead of searching each category array individually.

ex:

```
$allAchieves = file_get_contents('http://us.battle.net/api/wow/data/character/achievements');
$allAchieves = json_decode($allAchieves, true);

$generalAchieves = $allAchieves[achievements][0][achievements];
$quests = $allAchieves[achievements][1][categories];
$explorationAchieves = $allAchieves[achievements][2][categories];
$pvp = $allAchieves[achievements][3][categories];
$dungeonAndRaids = $allAchieves[achievements][4][categories];
$professions = $allAchieves[achievements][5][categories];
$reputation = $allAchieves[achievements][6][categories];
$scenarios = $allAchieves[achievements][7][categories];
$worldEvents = $allAchieves[achievements][8][categories];
$petbattle = $allAchieves[achievements][9][categories];
$featsOfStrength = $allAchieves[achievements][10][categories];
```

Hopefully someone can help, as the other threads I have seen sofar on array searching seem too simple to be of any help as the arrays they are dealing with are nothing to the size of the one I have here.

Comment: See if this helps http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Seems you will use this info a lot, so you don't have to fetch it every time you search; instead, you can cache a "flattened" copy (i.e. `{<id>:{"id":...},<id>:{"id":...}}`) on your server, and search that copy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I solved the issue using a different approach found here: 
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/8892160022?page=1#4